# How to chain together two collections of Tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, task-parallel-library, azure-functions

I'm attempting to run a collection of tasks, then once these have finished, run a separate collection of tasks. Essentially, the first collection of tasks are responsible for writing to some database tables, and the final collection of tasks collates the data from these tables into a reporting table.

An example of the code I'm using is below:

```
var dbWriteTasks = clients.Select(c => DoSomeWorkAsync(c)).ToArray();
var dbCollateTasks = clients.Select(c => DoSomeOtherWorkAsync(c));

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(dbWriteTasks, t => dbCollateTasks.ToArray());
```

This is running the first set of tasks successfully, but isn't running any of the second set of tasks, so I'm evidently doing something wrong.

I've also tried this to no avail:

```
var dbWriteTasks = clients.Select(c => DoSomeWorkAsync(c)).ToArray();
var dbCollateTasks = clients.Select(c => DoSomeOtherWorkAsync(c)).ToArray();

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(dbWriteTasks, t => dbCollateTasks);
```

This runs both sets of tasks, but the second set starts running and processing the data before the first set of tasks has finished inserting it...

I should also mention that I've tried running the two sets of tasks synchronously using `Task.WaitAll` but this hasn't worked either. I'm trying to do all of this inside an Azure function and `Task.WaitAll` just causes it to stop.

I'm relatively new to the TPL, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the factory methods use `await Task.WhenAll`. Using `await` allows you to seamlessly create continuations that read like synchronous code.

```
var dbWriteTasks = clients.Select(c => DoSomeWorkAsync(c))
var dbCollateTasks = clients.Select(c => DoSomeOtherWorkAsync(c));

await Task.WhenAll(dbWriteTasks);
await Task.WhenAll(dbCollateTasks);
```

Comment: All of the `ToList` and `ToArray` calls are superfluous.  If you want to simplify the code, that'd do more than just re-ordering operations whose order doesn't matter.

Comment: `I'm attempting to run a collection of tasks, then once these have finished, run a separate collection of tasks` Because of that requirement, I believe the first `await` should be moved before `var dbCollateTasks =  ...`

Comment: @KevinGossek correct me if I'm wrong but the `dbCollateTasks` won't run until the deffered query is enumerated in the second `WhenAll`.

Comment: Oh indeed, my bad. Not used to seeing IEnumerable mixed with tasks

Comment: While true, it's not a good idea to obfuscate your code like that and rely on IEnumerable deferred execution. Why not just move collate task initialization after first await?

Comment: Thanks @JSteward. It turns out that my problem was actually related to an SSH connection. Now that I've sorted that out, the approach you have described works as expected :)